# Rails activerecord query using select but return collection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want to perform a query that selects all users that are "allowed" to interact according to the following method:

**User.rb**

```
def allowed?(other_user)
  self.friends.include?(other.user) || self.followers.include?(other_user)
end
```

The problem is that `.select { |user| ... }` is returning an array, not a collection. How should I write the query correctly so further database queries can be appended (such as limit or order)?

**users controller**

```
@user = current_user

@users = User.select { |user| @user.allowed?(user) }
             .limit(100)
             .order(created_at: :desc)
             .paginate(page: params[:page])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `allowed?` method can be written as a class method as:

```
def self.allowed(other_user)
  User
    .joins(:friends, :followers)
    .where(
      'friends.user_id = :user_id OR followers.user_id = :user_id',
      user_id: other_user.id
    )
end
```

Which uses `joins` to specify the relationships of both friends and followers tables with users.

That makes allowed easily chainable, so you can have your `allowed?` method as a predicate in case you need it:

```
def self.allowed?(other_user)
  User.allowed(other_user).exists?
end
```

So you can do:

```
User
  .allowed(@user)
  .limit(100)
  .order(created_at: :desc)
  .paginate(page: params[:page])
```